# Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://translate.region.amazonaws.com/"

Tags: amazon-web-services

I was trying to run the basic cli example from the AWS [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/translate/latest/dg/get-started-cli.html) on AWS Translate service:

```
aws translate translate-text \
            --region region \
            --source-language-code "en" \
            --target-language-code "es" \
            --text "hello, world"
```

But I get:

```
Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://translate.region.amazonaws.com/"
```

My `~/.aws/config` file looks like this:

```
[default]
region = eu-central-1
output = json
```

I also tested this service from the AWS Console (via web ui) and it worked, what could cause it to fail?

Comment: There is no AWS region named "region"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specific region *eu-central-1* as per your question works

```
% aws translate translate-text \
            --region eu-central-1 \
            --source-language-code "en" \
            --target-language-code "es" \
            --text "hello, world"
{
    "TranslatedText": "hola, mundo",
    "SourceLanguageCode": "en",
    "TargetLanguageCode": "es"
}
```